# what is the probability that they getting on the bus?

Tags: probability, word-problem

Henry and Ann are waiting for a bus. They know from experience 
that if they wait for an hour, they will have a 90% chance of getting 
it. It is a chilly night, though, so Ann says, "Let's only stay out for 
10 minutes."

Henry says, "If we only wait for 10 minutes, we will only have a 
15% chance."

Ann replies, "Not true. We have a better chance than that."
Is Ann right? If so, what is the probability that they getting on the 
bus?

Answer (score 3):

If you assume the buses arrive regularly and Henry and Ann arrive at a random moment in the cycle (very strong assumptions, but we can do no better), the buses must come every $\frac {10}9$ hour.  If they wait $10$ min $=\frac 16$ hour, they have $\dfrac {\frac 16}{\frac {10}9}=\frac 9{60}=0.15$ chance of getting a bus, so Henry is right.  They might do well to study the bus schedule.

If the buses arrive randomly, the rate is to get one with $90\%$ chance in one hour is $\lambda=\ln 10$.  The chance for one not to arrive in $\frac 16$ hour is $e^{\frac{-\lambda}6}\approx 0.68$ so Ann would be right-they would have $32\%$ chance of getting one.

Comment: Or rather to study the actual distribution of buses, which may or may not be related to the schedule.

Comment: Hold on, if the buses arrive randomly, isn't the rate $\lambda = \ln(10)$ per hour?

Comment: @ErickWong:  Right you are.  Fixed.